# Change legend marker size for Plotly scatter plot (bubble chart) in Python

Tags: python, plotly

As I started modifying the Categorical Bubble Charts example found [here](https://plotly.com/python/bubble-charts/#categorical-bubble-charts), the size of the markers in the legend became so small they could not be seen.

Is there a way to control the legend marker size without changing the marker size in the plot?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The comment by anbjork found [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/modify-marker-size-in-legend/5338/12) gave me a great workaround:

```
fig.update_layout(legend= {'itemsizing': 'constant'})
```